# Facebook graph API: simple search for users by name

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, access-token, facebook-access-token

I would like to do a simple search for users by their name from a desktop application using Facebook's graph API. The result I want to have is a list of user names and the link to their profile. I spent several hours reading the documentation but it is still not very clear to me, which access tokens I would need. I have created a developer account on Facebook and added a new app. I've got an app access token and I've tried to do a search using the following URL:

[https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=john&access_token={my_app_access_token}](https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=john&access_token=%7Bmy_app_access_token%7D)

I got the following response:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "An unknown error has occurred.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 1
   }
}
```

My question now is, if it is possible to do such a simple search without user access token. So the user sitting in front of my desktop application should NOT have to enter his facebook credentials somewhere - never. Can this be done somehow?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When searching, you should provide the search type (in your case `user`) and to answer your question, no, a user access token is required to search, app tokens won't work for user searches (documented [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v1.0#search))

Comment: can you show one example. I tried to add search type and also the access token. I used the graph explorer to test.  but i too get OAuthException.  how can it be achieved?

Comment: Example search:
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/search?q=AdMe&type=page&fields=picture&access_token=<access-token-here>

Comment: @BjörnKaiser I am getting this `{
   "error": {
      "message": "Invalid OAuth access token.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 190,
      "fbtrace_id": "BzNqFjuIumD"
   }
}`

Comment: @YasserKhalil this answer, by now, is over 5 years old and I guess a lot has changed in this regard since. I recommend checking the documentation.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I already have a look and found the same strategy you offered but didn't work for me.